# Removing unwanted rows while importing text files and delimiting the data

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code which imports the notepad data to excel adding new column of the file name to it. The challenge now is, in the notepad there are unwanted rows are there in beginning and end of the data.

1. How can I removed that?
2. We normally do a delimited to the data, which is not happening while importing the file to excel.

The notepad has first five rows as below

Volume in drive Y has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 3000-0003

Directory of Y:\

Last two rows as below

```
          0 File(s)              0 bytes
        1796 Dir(s)  2,497,977,561,088 bytes free
```

Data is like this
12/19/2013  05:27 PM              User1

With the current Code i get the out put like this

Colum 1     = Abc_notepad1.text(textfile name)  Column2 = 12/19/2013  05:27 PM              User1

I want the code to remove the first five rows and last 2 rows
and the output like this
Column1 = ABC(first 3 letter of textfile name), Column2 = 12/19/2013  05:27 PM,  Column3 = ,   Column4 = User1

```
Option Explicit

Const myPath = "D:\My Data\"
Const delim = vbTab

Sub MergeMultipleTextFiles()
    Dim myFile As String        'filename
    Dim strRecord As String     'record string
    Dim arrRecord()             'record array
    Dim fNum As Integer         'free file number
    Dim RowCounter As Long      'row counter
    Dim i As Long               'loop variable

    On Error GoTo errHandler
    myFile = Dir(myPath & "*.txt")

    RowCounter = 0
    Do While myFile <> ""
        fNum = FreeFile
        Open myPath & myFile For Input As #fNum

        Do While Not EOF(fNum)
            'read in the row into the record variable
            Line Input #fNum, strRecord
            'add the filename to the record variable
            strRecord = myFile & delim & strRecord

            RowCounter = RowCounter + 1
            'resize the record array
            ReDim Preserve arrRecord(1 To RowCounter)
            arrRecord(RowCounter) = Split(strRecord, delim)
        Loop

        Close #fNum
        'get the next file in the directory
        myFile = Dir()
    Loop
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
        For i = 1 To RowCounter
            .Offset(i - 1).Resize(, UBound(arrRecord(i)) + 1).Value = arrRecord(i)
        Next i
    End With

errExit:
    'close all open text files
    Reset
    Exit Sub
errHandler:
    'error message goes here
    Resume errExit
End Sub
```

Comment: Data is like below
Column1         Column 2
Text - 1.txt    05/20/2013  10:41 AM    <DIR>          User

Comment: Give your example data like this: Column1 = ".." Column2 = ".." etc.

Comment: updated the fields in main question itself

Answer (score 0):

Q1 - Bypass first 5 rows:

```
For i1 = 1 to 5
  Line Input #fNum, strRecord
Next i1
```

Q2 - Bypass last 2 rows:

```
  If InStr(1, strRecord, "File(s)" > 0 then exit Do
```

Q3 - Get Columns:

```
  Column1 = Left$(textfilename, 3)
  Column2 = Left$(data, 19)
  Column3 = ""
  Column4 = mid$(data, 21)
```

Comment: Thank you so much..for you help

Comment: Hi I was on medical emergency.. so i couldnt execute this.. can i know where to update this code?

Comment: Answer 1 goes in front of `Do While myFile <> ""`. Answer 2 goes after `strRecord = myFile & delim & strRecord`. I think Answer 3 goes after `strRecord = myFile & delim & strRecord`, somewhere where `Data is like this 12/19/2013 05:27 PM User1`. Accept if this answers your question.